# css selector for text inside a label and using a before and after

Tags: css

This my first question, so I hope that I ask it correctly.

Matthew Cain has created a great example of a fancy radio button using html and css  which can be seen at https://www.templatemonster.com/blog/style-checkboxes-radio-buttons-css/. In it he uses this code:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

#first {
  background-color: #4B4D65;
}

#second {
  background-color: #FF8A66;
}

.section {
  padding: 100px;
  padding-left: 150px;
}

.section input[type="radio"],
.section input[type="checkbox"]{
  display: none;
}

.container {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container label {
  position: relative;
}


/* Base styles for spans */
.container span::before,
.container span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Radio buttons */
.container span.radio:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container span.radio::before {
  left: -52px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #A8AAC1;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.container span.radio::after {
  left: -49px;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #6C788A;
  transition: left .25s, background-color .25s;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label span.radio::after {
  left: -27px;
  background-color: #EBFF43;
}

<section id="first" class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <input type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-1">
      <label for="radio-1"><span class="radio">Coffee</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <input type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-2">
      <label for="radio-2"><span class="radio">Tea</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <input type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-3">
      <label for="radio-3"><span class="radio">Cappuccino</span></label>
    </div>
</section>
```

When I debug it in Chrome I see

```
<span class="radio"> == $0
 ::before
 "Coffee"
 ::after
</span"
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<body class="my_PageBg" data-usepopupcontrols="no">
<div class="my_DesktopContainer my_temp_unselect" style="display: none;">
<div tabindex="1" class="container" 
id="radio1" style="transform-origin: center 50%; left: 20px; top: 40px;     width: 660px; height: 100px; 
overflow: auto; position: absolute; z-index: 1; direction: ltr; transform:         inherit; transform-style: preserve-3d;" 
contenteditable="false">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">
<label style="cursor: default;" onkeydown="onTreeLabelKeyDown(event)"     for="radio10" name="radio1">
<input name="radio1" tabindex="1" id="radio10"     onclick='OnResetDownChainControls("radio1",event)' type="radio" checked=""     value="Value1"/>
Val1
</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 0px; white-space: nowrap;">
<label style="cursor: default;" onkeydown="onTreeLabelKeyDown(event)"     for="radio11" name="radio1">
<input name="radio1" tabindex="1" id="radio11"     onclick='OnResetDownChainControls("radio1",event)' type="radio" value="Value2"/>
Val2
</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 0px; white-space: nowrap;"><label style="cursor:     default;" onkeydown="onTreeLabelKeyDown(event)" for="radio12" name="radio1">
<input name="radio1" tabindex="1" id="radio12"     onclick='OnResetDownChainControls("radio1",event)' type="radio" value="Value3"/>
    Val3
</label>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I am trying to do the same to the Text "Val1", "Val2", "etc.

Please note that I can not change the html since it is coming from an external call.

What css selector can I use?

Comment: "I am trying to do the same to the Text "Val1"  What does this mean?

Comment: ksav, The word Val1 occurs in my HTML right before the close label tag.  This is the text that I am referring to.

Comment: You need to change the html for that effect.

Answer (score 0):

[::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) and [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo-elements do not apply to [replaced-elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#replaced-elements) or [void-elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#void-elements).

But you can use a `<span>` to achieve the desired effect. Example:

```css
.my-special-class:before {
  content: '[before] ';
}
.my-special-class:after {
  content: ' [after]';
}
.my-special-class:before,
.my-special-class:after {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="my-special-class">Val 1</span>
```

Obviously, you can name the class to whatever you want and change the selectors accordingly.

**Note:** if you want to use pseudo-elements as graphics (to give them size, `position`, `background-image`, `border`, `background`, etc – without actual `content`) you ***must*** still specify `content: ''` (empty string). Without setting `content`, the pseudo-element will not render, regardless of `display`, `visibility` or `opacity`.
Most CSS attributes that can be applied to a normal DOM element can be applied to [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

`<label>`s can have pseudo's, but that would mean the `:before` gets placed before the `<input>`, which is included in the `<label>`. If you want to place the `:before` after the `<input>` (which cannot have pseudo's), you have to wrap the text node in a `<span>`, as in the example.

Also note that, even though the spec defines pseudo elements officially with double colon notation (`::pseudo-element`), all browsers supporting double colon notation also support the legacy single colon notation, while a few legacy versions (IE pre v9, FF pre v1.5, Opera pre v7) only support the single colon notation. For this reason, most people use the single colon notation (which is, officially, wrong, but technically right, at least for now).

Comment: Andrei, Thank you for your answer.  However, I can not change the html since it is coming from an external call.  So I can not add a span, etc.

Comment: Well, you can't have pseuos on either `textNodes` or `<input>`s. So you can't achieve the effect in the example. But, trust me, you **can** change the HTML, at any point you like. Using JavaScript. You can take any one DOM node and replace it with another, having the "old" one as contents.

Comment: Thank Andrei.  I will use jquery to adjust the html and do the styling.